# how to run endlessh tarpit on startup in the background on ubuntu server?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-20.04

I wanted to try this [ssh tarpit](https://github.com/skeeto/endlessh) and could start it on my server.

My server is running Ubuntu 20.04.

But I wanted to automate the execution of it when the server reboots.
I tried a systemd service but with no luck. It could also be my lack of knowledge with this stuff.

Can someone help me to get this tarpit script to run on server startup ?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: This program is already packaged by Ubuntu. Did you try it? It should already come with a systemd service: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/endlessh

Comment: Oh I did not know this. I installed it via apt install endlessh now. But how do I change the settings like the port it listens to? The dir under /etc/endlessh/config that is mentioned in the man page is missing. And how would the config file look like? I am quite new to this server part .

Comment: I tried to create a config file by using touch config and just pasting the example from git I linked in my post. But the port still reamains 2222 and does not change. I reboot after I make changes but it does not help. There must be a stupid mistake I am making.

Comment: I found the changlelog (I assume) and on the page there was the path to the service file https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/endlessh_1.1-2_amd64.deb.html
I opened the service file and there was a comment about changing the port it listens to. But I do not understand how the port gets changed by this (or where I must do it) 

`## If you want Endlessh to bind on ports < 1024

## 1) run:
##     setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/local/bin/endlessh
## 2) uncomment following line
#AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
## 3) comment following line
PrivateUsers=true
`

Comment: @A.B I forgot to mention you I assume. Sry if my posts are not easy to understand. I think there is sth to be done with the last comment about the service file and the comment inside it. But I don't get it how I am supposed to do it.